# reddit data collecting stops halfway through the php loop

Tags: php, loops, reddit, array-merge

Guys I have using this code to grab data from reddit.com post... this works fine until 1500 posts(i need to get data of 10000). then it give an error saying

> array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

this error triggers from the line where i have wrote `array_merge`

the code

```
<?php
$count = 0;
for($digit=0; $count<2001; $digit+=1){

        $jsondata = trim(file_get_contents("http://www.reddit.com/new/.json?count=$count&limit=100"));

        $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);

        $postdata[$digit] = $json['data']['children'];
        $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $postdata[$digit]);

        }

        foreach($mergedArray as $livedata){

            $output .= $livedata["data"]["ups"].", ";
            $output .= '"'.$livedata["data"]["title"].'", ';
            $output .= $livedata["data"]["id"].", ";
            $output .= $livedata["data"]["num_comments"].", ";
            $output .= $livedata["data"]["domain"]."\n\r";
            $output .= "<br />";

        }
        echo $output;
        ?>
```

can any body spot the error and let me know a way for me to get 10000 posts uninteruppted

Comment: anybody please help me??

Answer (score 1):

It would be incredibly more helpful if you provided the response body you got when that happens; it's likely you've received an error message.

I don't know if this is why you're running into an error now, but your approach has two issues that you'll run into sooner or later.

The first is that per [the API rules](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API#rules), you should probably be authenticating as an app and should be specifying a user agent; otherwise you'll be throttled heavily.  It's reasonably likely you're receiving 429s now, but not checking for them.

Secondly, listing pages on reddit only cover 1,000 items, so you won't be able to directly fetch 10,000 items from them.  If you actually need 10k items, you have two primary choices:

1. Collect data 1000 items at a time over a period of time.
2. Get really fancy with the search api and timestamps to get many slices of data that you can piece together.

You haven't specified why you need this data (or why you need 10,000 samples), but if you're merely looking for a selection of reddit posts on which to perform some analysis, other people have created data sets of [posts](https://github.com/umbrae/reddit-top-2.5-million) and [comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/3bxlg7/i_have_every_publicly_available_reddit_comment/).